# How to set up your own PEAR Channel?

Tags: php, deployment, pear

I am looking for instructions on how to setup a PEAR channel for our project so that we can deploy it with the pear installer. I have searched the web for a while and cannot find any straightforward information. I followed [this tutorial](http://greg.chiaraquartet.net/archives/123-Setting-up-your-own-PEAR-channel-with-Chiara_PEAR_Server-the-official-way.html) for a while, but I am having a hell of a time getting this to work. Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: This is a great question.  I can't find this information anywhere either.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but I am curious about why the tutorial hasn't worked for you.  Where in the process listed on that link are you getting stuck?

Comment: It would be good if you let us know where you are stuck. Otherwise, I'd recommend checking out #pear on EFnet. We frequently help people setup servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are one of the few people who want to do this. That tutorial you linked to appears to be the latest (!) but the package is still [somewhat in development](http://pear.chiaraquartet.net/index.php?package=Chiara_PEAR_Server). The documentation in that package is also non-existent. It looks like it's up to you to write the docs. Or maybe contact [Greg Beaver](http://greg.chiaraquartet.net/); the author of the package and blog post you linked to. He also [wrote a book about PEAR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1904811191) (albeit in 2006.) The amazon writeup mentions this:

> Next, you will learn how to set up
>   your own PEAR Channel for distributing
>   PHP applications, both open-source and
>   proprietary closed-source PHP
>   applications that can be secured using
>   technology already built into the PEAR
>   Installer

.

Comment: Thanks, MDCore. That's the best answer (and only) I've got so I am marking it answered. I'll try and hunt down that book.

Answer (score 2):

What problems are you encountering on following the tutorial that you linked to?

You could set up your own channel with pirum or the chiara server ( http://pear.chiaraquartet.net/ ) but you could also look into getting an account on http://pearfarm.org and hosting your packages there (or on http://pearhub.org).

Answer (score 2):

The PEAR [website lists a number of channel server](http://pear.php.net/channels/) softwares now (bottom of the page).
They are:

- [Chiara_PEAR_Server](http://pear.chiaraquartet.net/)
- [SimpleChannelServer](http://pear.chiaraquartet.net/)
- [Pirum](http://www.pirum-project.org/)
- [Pearfarm](http://pearfarm.org/)

I would not use the chiara pear server anymore; it's dead.