# Managing External and Internal Libraries in Codeigniter with PEAR

Tags: php, codeigniter, pear

I want to start using more libraries for my codeigniter project, but I am weary of having them all in my vcs or having to manually manage versions of the libraries. I've recently found this [PEAR Guide](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PEAR_integration/) but I don't see anything about existing codeigniter libraries being available through this system. Does a CI specific PEAR repo exist and if not, how difficult is it to get packages into PEAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your own pear channel server (i.e. via [pirum](http://www.pirum-project.org/), [pearhub](http://www.pearhub.org/) or [pearfarm](http://pearfarm.org/)) and put your own package in there. it's not that hard to build your own packages - you can even automate it with a phing script.

See also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168136/282601) here on Stackoverflow with a more complete list of channel servers.